# how to convert and sum shap_values

Tags: python, pandas, shap

I have used shap_values for my machine learning model, which I want to sum part of the columns and plot. I am using this code:

```
import shap
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)

rows_pd = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=X_columns)
shap_values = explainer(rows_pd)
```

and would like to perform:

`df_shap_values = pd.DataFrame(shap_values)`

and then:

`df_shap_values_sum = df_shap_values.T.groupby(['key1']).sum().T`

but I couldnt find a way to convert shap_values to dataframe.

Is there a way of converting to df and summing up shap_values?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share what you have in `shop_values`?

Comment: Please add [reprex]